# Remove duplicate from different columns in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have table :

```
number city1 city2 mentions
1 a b 5
1 b a 5
1 c d 2
1 d c 2
```

what I need is to remove duplicate records, such as a, b equal to b,a became :

```
number city1 city2 mentions
1 a b 5
1 c d 2
```

any clue for me ?

thanks before :)

Comment: please indent your question.use ctrl-K.

Comment: Could you format your table content  using "Code sample" feature?

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
delete from table t1
where exists (
  select *
  from table t2
  where
    t2.number = t1.number and
    t2.city1 = t1.city2 and
    t2.city2 = t1.city1 and
    t2.mentions = t1.mentions and
    t2.city1 < t2.city2
)
```